# How to determine VMware ESX server requirements for n VMs?

Tags: vmware-esxi, database, hardware, vmware-esx, application-server

I am going to buy a high-end server for my department's daily usage. On this server, I am planning to launch 2 DB servers, 2 Application Servers and around 10 ordinary development PCs on the VMware ESXi infrasturture. The exact Spec of each VM is clear for me.

Is there any guideline to propose me which hardware spec best suites to by requirements?

Comment: Sure. Look @ individual VM's CPU, Memory, Disk, IOPS requirements, and add them together. That should give you a starting point of what you need as a bare minimum.

Comment: Could they really be added simply? I thought a best practice should exist for VMware technologies.

Comment: Please consider to put each DB on each own SSD drive.

Answer (score 0):

Add up the number of virtual CPUs and amount of memory required.

Subject to some qualifications (Microsoft Exchange for example), a relatively safe overcommit for vcpu:cpu is approximately 4:1 for server workloads.  I personally prefer not to overcommit memory, as that's relatively inexpensive.

For storage, total the required amount of GB, and then the IOPS, their read:write ratio, and the average block size.  Adjust the IOPS required based on the read:write ratio, and your desired storage RAID type.

Purchase the number of disks (or shared storage resources) to meet your GB and performance requirements.